# how to join these tables properly in sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

I have 3 tables. First there is Posts tables which looks like this

| id | post_creator |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mark |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | David |
| 4 | Ellie |
| 5 | Thomas |
| 6 | Elliot |

There are 2 types of post. image post and text post. I have 2 different tables for them. Here's how text_posts table look like:

| post_id | post_text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | lorem ipsum |
| 4 | lorem ipsum |
| 5 | lorem ipsum |

again there's an image_posts table both follows id from posts table

| post_id | post_text | post_image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | lorem ipsum | image_url |
| 3 | lorem ipsum | image_url |
| 6 | lorem ipsum | image_url |

Now I dont care about post_image urls, all I want is to get post_creator from Post table along with post whether its in text_post table or image_post table I want the texts. How can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps you can get inspiration from [UNION](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-union/) statement, which can join two queries as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using a SQL Db.

In this case, Posts and post_text/image_posts are a NtoN relationship so you should normalize the relationship as 2 1toN.
In this case it ends with 1 table Post, 2 Table: Post_text and Post_img and another table that maintains the "history" of post per each user.
You should create another table named Creates(id, user_id, post_id).

Then you can join the 2 table and obtain the post_creator.

```
SELECT 
     post_id, post_text, post_image
FROM Posts 
     LEFT JOIN text_posts ON text_posts.post_id = Posts.id
     LEFT JOIN image_posts ON image_posts.post_id = Posts.id
```

Then you will obtain a table having all the field of the tables as result. To understand if the post is an image one just check the post_image field. If it is != null then it would be an image_post.

However, the structure you used is very bad, I suggest you to study a bit better how to structure a SQL table and Db and try to re-structure your data in a better way, following the Normalization rules.